# UserControl Constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor

My Problem is
when I want to use UserControl with parameter.

it call both constructor( constructor with no parameter  And constroctor with parameters)

is this normal situation??

if not, how should I construct the object.

```
public partial class FreeExperience : Arche.Web.UI.UserControlBase
{
    private ItemInfo itemInfo;
    public FreeExperience() : base()
    {
    }
    public FreeExperience(ItemInfo itemInfo) : this()
    {
        this.itemInfo = itemInfo;
    }
```

here I made simple userControl ,

and Call it like this on the another page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="FreeExperience" Src="include/FreeExperience.ascx" %>
```

...

```
<uc:FreeExperience ID="ucFreeExperience" runat="server"/>
```

And On the  `Page_load` function of this webpage's CS

```
ucFreeExperience = new Arche.Itempage3.include.FreeExperience(itemInfo);
```

Comment: After Removing : this() I get same result.   is this normal??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dont use constructors on user controls.

Expose properties with get/set accessors.

Answer (score 1):

```
public FreeExperience(ItemInfo itemInfo) : this()
```

:this()  is calling your default constructor, if there is no specific reason why you are doing so, you can remove it.

Actually, I always operate the other way around, and have constructors with little or no parameter, call a parametered constructor, providing default values.

Comment: After Removing  : this()   I get same result.  could you specifically explain about your way to use UC ?